# Obtain the total uid for each type

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to find how many user brought a product (Note : I don't need total no of users only how many users brought).

Table name : buyer

```
+-----+----------+---------+
| id  | products |    uid  |
|-----|----------|---------|
| 1   |  soap    |    2    |
| 2   |  h_oil   |    1    |
| 3   |  soap    |    3    |
| 4   |  tea     |    1    |
| 5   |  soap    |    2    |
| 6   |  h_oil   |    1    |
| 7   |  soap    |    3    |
| 8   |  tea     |    1    |
+-----+----------+---------+
```

I need a result like this table given below:

```
|-----|---------------|--------------|
| id  | product_name  |  total_user  |
|-----|---------------|--------------|
| 1   |  soap         |      2       |
| 2   |  h_oil        |      1       |
| 3   |  tea          |      1       |
|------------------------------------|
```

How can I do that in a MySQL query?

Comment: Yeah you will need to use `group by` and `count`.

Comment: Please look at [my edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/16419189/revisions) and see the difference it's made to how your question is presented to everyone else. There's a preview box beneath which you can use to view your question before posting...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 SELECT products product_name, COUNT(DISTINCT uid) total_user FROM purchases GROUP BY products;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use:

```
SELECT product_name, COUNT(*) AS total_user FROM buyer GROUP BY product_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(*) 
FROM
    buyer
GROUP BY
    products
```

Answer (score 0):

In short, you are looking for a `group by` statement

```
SELECT uid, product_name, count(id) as total_user FROM buyer GROUP BY uid
```

read more here:

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html

Comment: `GROUP BY uid` will group the results by user ID, the question was to count the number of buys of the products from no matter which user

Comment: ya i need result by user id

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(id) 
FROM
    buyer
GROUP BY
    products
```